# Class to be used to store objects of different classes?

Tags: java, collections

Which class should i use to make a collection of different types? i am getting error while having an ArrayList or LinkedList of objects of different classes.

```
import java.util.*;
class A extends Object {
    private String name;
    A(String n) {   name = n;}
    public String toString() {  return name;}
}
class B extends Object {
    private String name;
    B(String n) {name = n;}
    public String toString() { return name;}
}

class c {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList ml= new ArrayList();
        ml.add(new A("1"));
        ml.add(new A("2"));

        Iterator itr = ml.iterator();
        B b = new B("1001");
        ml.add(b);

        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            Object element = itr.next();
            System.out.println(element + "\n");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: And pray tell us what that error may be.

Comment: post your code please

Comment: See my answer, whether there is a workaround but I am curious what you are upto?

Comment: I have posted link to my code .please help

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would define an `Interface` which contains all the methods which these particular objects share. You would then define a list which takes members which implement that particular interface.

My suggestion assumes that the items in the same collection share some common behaviour.

```
List<MyInterface> list = new ArrayList<MyInterface>();
...
```

Another approach would be to not define any types at all:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
...
```

The difference between the two approaches is that for the first, you know exactly what you have and what you can use. There needs to be no casting/checking and certain errors can be caught at compile time. However, the first approach requires some more thinking during the design phase.

The latter is more of a catch all scenario, however it requires that you make checks and other mechanisms to be sure of what type of object you are working with.

Comment: Woo hoo for a real answer!

Answer (score 0):

Code in post trow exception: **java.util.ConcurrentModificationException**.

Reason for this exeption - changing list after getting iterator.
You should change list before get iterator.

Please check article http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html

Comment: And this? What's this got to do with anything?

Comment: here is the link to my code. please help:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K7Gd3nFYQvlTESYWnoFXyJ4JRiMm03iAY5ci9SrRUSc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You trying to change list after getting iterator...http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have different objects first define any similarities they all share. Now make a super class or an interface which the object classes extends or implements. Then define a List of the high level interface or super class. In the runtime cast the objects in the list with the particular object if you know. Otherwise match the object type with all the object type you are considering.

Another method can be make an List of Object class. In the runtime cast to the appropriate object or just like previous match the retrieved object with your collection of different object types.

The above procedures should be easy to code.